Undefined while getting session in API, next-auth
I'm trying to create a menu. If the user role is "1000", I want to add "AddNewUser" item to menu, otherwise this section shouldn't be appear. I can get session on my dashboard.jsx so normally session is correct, but I can't get it in my API. How can I fix that?
Here is my session information coming from dashboard:

Here is terminal:

nextauth:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import sql from "mssql";
import db from "../../../../../lib/db";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login-1',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'demo@example.com' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const pool = await sql.connect(db);
          const sqlRequest = pool.request();

          const userQuery = `
            SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, password, role_id, location_id FROM [inventory].[user] WHERE email = @Email
          `;

          sqlRequest.input('Email', sql.VarChar, credentials.email);
          const result = await sqlRequest.query(userQuery);
          const user = result.recordset[0];

          if (user) {
            const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(credentials.password, user.password);

            if (isValidPassword) {
              console.log("User Role Assigned:", user.role_id);
              return {
                id: user.id,
                name: `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`,
                email: user.email,
                role: user.role_id,
                location: user.location_id
              };
            }
          }

          return null;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('An error occurred during authorization:', error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.role = user.role;
        token.location = user.location;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.role = token.role;
        session.user.location = token.location;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});


export { handler, handler as GET, handler as POST };

API:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getMenus } from "./menu-items";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"

export async function GET(req, { params }) {
  const session = await getServerSession({ req });

  if (!session || !session.user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
  }

  const user = session.user;
  console.log("role:", user.role);

  const menus = await getMenus(params?.locale ?? "en-US", user.role);
  return NextResponse.json(menus, { status: 200 });
}

menu-item:
import { getDictionary } from "@app/[lang]/dictionaries";

export async function getMenus(locale, userRole) {
  const dictionary = await getDictionary(locale);
  const { sidebar } = dictionary;

  const baseMenu = [
    {
      path: `/${locale}/dashboards/dashboard`,
      label: sidebar.menuItem.dashboard,
      icon: "dashboard",
    },
    {
      path: `/${locale}/dashboards/misc`,
      label: sidebar.menuItem.addNewMachine,
      icon: "editor",
    },
    {
      path: `/${locale}/dashboards/addThirdPartyData`,
      label: sidebar.menuItem.addData,
      collapsible: true,
      icon: "editor",
    },
    {
      path: `/${locale}/dashboards/listing`,
      label: sidebar.menuItem.machineList,
      icon: "listing",
    },
    {
      path: `/${locale}/modules/maps/clustering`,
      label: sidebar.menu.maps,
      icon: "map",
    },
  ];

  console.log(userRole);

  if (userRole === 1000) {
    console.log("Role check passed, adding addNewUser to menu"); 
    baseMenu.push({
      path: `/${locale}/dashboards/addNewUser`,
      label: sidebar.menuItem.addNewUser,
      icon: "user",
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Role check failed, addNewUser not added to menu"); 
  }

  return [
    {
      label: sidebar.menu.home,
      children: baseMenu,
    },
  ];

 
}


can you please provide error in  from_picture_to_code_format
